# Portable Strawberry perl

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I download the portable strawberry perl version perl-5.18.1.1 from http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html and unzip it

When I run the protableshell.bat

and then run  cpan> install some::module

i get always the below error message "The system cannot find the path specified."

below an example of the error i get when trying to install Text::CSV_XS for example

```
Welcome to Text::CSV (v.1.32)
=============================
If you install Text::CSV_XS v.0.99, it makes Text::CSV faster.

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Text::CSV
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
The system cannot find the path specified.
  MAKAMAKA/Text-CSV-1.32.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry-perl-5.18.1.1-64bit-portable\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Text::CSV'.
Failed during this command:
 MAKAMAKA/Text-CSV-1.32.tar.gz                : make NO
```

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: Does `dmake` exist in the path specified?

Comment: Yes i checked it and it exist in the path .

Comment: Are you able to manually install a module?

Comment: Yes downloading them manualy and installing them using dmake install works

Answer (score 2):

I am using 64 Bit Portable Perl Version - 5.18.2.2 and tried installing the module. Seems to work fine for me. Kindly try the following steps:

After you install portable perl, you need to

1) change to to directory where you have installed it

2) run the portableshell.bat command.

3) Check and reconfirm if the right perl version is running.

```
C:\Users\pmu>cd C:\myperl64_51822

C:\myperl64_51822>portableshell.bat
----------------------------------------------
Welcome to Strawberry Perl Portable Edition!
* URL - http://www.strawberryperl.com/
* see README.TXT for more info
----------------------------------------------
Perl executable: C:\myperl64_51822\perl\bin\perl.exe
Perl version   : 5.18.2 / MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

C:\myperl64_51822>perl --version | find /I "version"
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
```

4) use the cpanm command instead of cpan. It works for me as shown below.

```
C:\myperl64_51822>cpanm Text::CSV_XS
--> Working on Text::CSV_XS
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/H/HM/HMBRAND/Text-CSV_XS-1.05.tgz ... OK
Configuring Text-CSV_XS-1.05 ... OK
Building and testing Text-CSV_XS-1.05 ... OK
Successfully installed Text-CSV_XS-1.05
1 distribution installed

C:\myperl64_51822>
```

Note - It took a long time to install the module. I hit Ctrl+C after a long time and the above message came up.

Hope this helps.